# Do c++ inline functions have to be declared in same file?

Tags: c++, function, header, inline

I have a header file with all the declarations, one .cpp file that is compiled to a .o file and a .cpp file with the main method.

The strange thing is, the program won't compile (I'm using g++ on cygwin) when a certain function in the .o file is declared inline in the header; only when declared normally.

So, do inline functions have to be declared in the same file that they're used?

Comment: The definition for an `inline` function has to be visible in every translation unit that uses it. This usually means putting the definition in a header file.

Comment: @Simple That should be an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, do inline functions have to be declared in the same file that they're used?

All functions (and, in general, all named entities) must be *declared* before use; an inline function must also be *defined* in every translation unit in which it is odr-used.

For this reason, they are usually defined in headers, so that the definition can be included in more than one translation unit.

Comment: I see! Thanks, that should be easy to fix.